# Visual Studio Google Android Emulator

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a ionic cordova project. I use Visual Studio 2015 and I run "Google Android Emulator" but I get error in attacment error.

[image: visual studio 2015 google android emulator]

Comment: Does this problem occurs when using VS Emulator for Android?

Comment: No. I use Google Android Emulator. My pc doesn't support Hyper-V. @ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: My project is running in Ripple Emulator but it isn't running in Device and Google Adroid Emulator. @ElvisXia-MSFT